# How to save profile pic and display in edit account page woo-commerce

Tags: woocommerce, user-accounts

I want to add upload profile field and save it in edit account page without any plugin in woocommerce.

I added the below code in functions.php to add profile photo in account page

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'add_profile_imageto_edit_account_form' );
function add_profile_imageto_edit_account_form() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    ?>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="favorite_color"><?php _e( 'Upload Profile Photo', 'woocommerce' ); ?>  </label>
            <input type="file" name="profile_image" id="profile_image" placeholder="Upload Profile Photo" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

Suggest me anybody how to do save this data and display the saved data in edit account page.

Answer (score 0):

i put this code `<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide"> <label for="favorite_color"><?php _e( 'Upload Profile Photo', 'woocommerce' ); ?>  </label> <input type="file" name="profile_image" id="profile_image" placeholder="Upload Profile Photo" /> </p>`

in the edit account page , but i cont find function page, where is it?

Comment: Answer post should not contain question. Queries or suggestions regarding main question must be maintain in the comment section only

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.